# use Create a PaymentMethod with PaymentElement

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have used this [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?client=react) to create an embedded payment form. This is my code in CheckoutForm.jsx,

```
const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
    paymentMethodOrder: ['card'],
    fields: {
      billingDetails: {
        name: 'auto',
        email: 'auto',
        address: {
          country: 'never'
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

for this I get an error when removing country

And also name and email not getting displayed. Is there a way to do this,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is expected, as mentionned in the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-fields):

> If you disable the collection of a certain field with the `fields` option, you must pass that same data to `stripe.confirmPayment` or the payment will be rejected.

So for example if you disable the `country` field, then you need to pass the country when confirming the PaymentIntent like this:

```
stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements: elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: "https://...",
    payment_method_data: {
      billing_details: {
        address: {
          country: 'US' 
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks and is there any solution for adding email and name fields?

Comment: If you want some fields to always show up, then the solution is to set them to `never` on Stripe side, and then add you own input fields above the Payment Element.